# How to Set user name and Password of phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

how to set username and password of phpmyadmin

I am using xampp software for localhost and I want to lock my phpmyadmin page 
when I open this link `

> localhost/phpmyadmin

its opening direct now and I want to lock this page and use username and password

example when I open this page

> localhost/phpmyadmin

its required username and password

how can I do this please help me to fix this issue

thanks

Comment: You can try to realize basic HTTP authentication on phpmyadmin index page. Additional information - http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Closed or not, this question helped me.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply open the phpmyadmin page from your browser, then open any existing database -> go to Privileges tab, click on your root user and then a popup window will appear, you can set your password there..
Hope this Helps.

Comment: now not showing any tables in phpmyadmin page and showing this error i want do default 
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: try :
Go to file C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\config.inc.php (I guess you would replace "wamp" with the name of your server if you're not using Wamp Server)

Find the line $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']='' and change this to

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']='NO'
Try opening phpMyAdmin again, and hopefully the message will now read "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Now change the password in the above line to 'yourpassword' (whatever you had set it to before)

Comment: i am using xampp software not wamp server

Comment: go to C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php
Look for the line where :
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
and set the new password,the save.
now go to localhost/phpmyadmin , it should open with you.

Comment: Thank You Ahmed Ali! editing the config.inc.php file and manually adding the correct new password worked!

Comment: what about the user name of the phpmyadmin

Comment: what you mean @danielad?

Comment: After doing this I get `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` !