# how to protect PHP my admin access

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

How can I protect PHPMYADMIN with password? I mean that whenever I will go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` it will ask for username and password, only after given the right username and password, it will allow the user to view all of the databases, tables and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best way to secure phpmyadmin is to uninstall it..

Comment: Isn't it always protected with a password?

Comment: @HenkJansen working localy

Comment: Does this question help you? :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010819/how-to-set-user-name-and-password-of-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

PHPMyAdmin should ask for a user already, unless you somehow avoid the log in if you're on localhost.

Either way, from PHPMyAdmin you can create and edit users. Simply add a user to view the database with, and make sure there are no accounts that can see the database **without** a username and password.